# Port Forwarding Raspberry Pi 3 on a College Network

Tags: networking, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, dyndns, home-automation

In order to get some home automation software to work, I need to have public access to my Raspberry Pi 3. However, I currently reside in an on-campus dorm and as a result am on the college's network and do not have the ability to port forward.

I have a router that connects to the school network via Ethernet and then broadcasts its own network, however, this is still a part of the school's network and I can't port forward this.

I've looked into ways to get around this such as Page Kite, using some form of reverse SSH or HTTPS tunneling, but due to lack of support on Raspberry Pi or daunting setup I'm not really sure what to do. I do have an old HP laptop on Windows 7 that I could use as some sort of slave or server if that would help.

All help is very much appreciated. This has been a major roadblock in me finishing this project.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of public access you're expecting, but without access to the main router you just need to signup for a **dynamic DNS service** with a client-based updating tool. All the most known ones (DynDNS Dynu, no-ip) all offer that option as far as I know.

The theory is that you keep the service updated anytime your internal WAN IP changes and they keep your hand-picked url updated with that IP. Then you can access your Pi with that IP thru a web browser or whatever service/port you've setup.

Here's a good starting article - with links to Dynu downloads for Linux that should work for you.

http://www.howtogeek.com/66438/how-to-easily-access-your-home-network-from-anywhere-with-ddns/

And an article from noip.com site on installing their Linux update client
https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client/